# Text resize not working in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/dpom33bh/7/) which is dynamically resizing the text.

Right now the text is inside the span but i want to be in the div like that

```
<div id="h2"  class='jtextfill2' >

</div >
```

But my code just not working when i change h2 to div. The id is passing to the code like

```
$('.jtextfill2').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 36 },'h2');
```

But i am wondering why it is not working ?

Comment: Actually, [it is working](http://jsfiddle.net/ywu31fw3/) (remember to update CSS as well).

Comment: update to this in css `h2, div#h2 {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick you can pull is to compare the actual height of the `<div>` with `height` set to `auto`, vs the height when set to max height (150px in you case):

Example:

```
$.fn.textfill = function (options, targetid) {
    var target = $("#" + targetid);
    var fontSize = options.maxFontPixels;
    var maxHeight = target.height();
    var maxWidth = target.width();
    var neededSize, actualSize;

    var neededHeight;

    do {
        target.css('font-size', fontSize);

        // See what would be the height of the container, at
        // a given font size, if we'd give it any space it needs.
        target.css('height', 'auto');
        neededHeight = target.height();

        fontSize = fontSize - 1;

    // Condition: needed height is larger then the max height.
    } while (neededHeight > maxHeight && (fontSize > 3));

    // Restore original height.
    target.css('height', maxHeight); 

    return this;
}
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywu31fw3/4/).

---

As a sidenote: in jsFiddle, you can use a separate box for Javascript, no need to use `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
        (function($) {
            //  alert("f");
            $.fn.textfill = function(options,targetid) {
                var fontSize = options.maxFontPixels;
                var maxHeight = $("#"+targetid).height();
                var maxWidth = $("#"+targetid).width();
                var textHeight;
                var textWidth;
                var text = $("#"+targetid).text();


                do {
                    $("#"+targetid).css('font-size', fontSize);
                    $("#"+targetid).append("<span class='texthight'>"+text+"</span>"); 
                    textHeight = $('.texthight').height();
                    $('.texthight').remove();
                    textWidth = $("#"+targetid).width();
                    fontSize = fontSize - 1;
                } while ((textHeight > maxHeight || textWidth > maxWidth) && (fontSize > 3));
                return this;
            }
        })(jQuery);

        $('.jtextfill2').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 50 },'h2');

<!-- //-----------------HTml--------------------//    --> 
<h2 id="h2"  class='jtextfill2' >
      aaSamp sfd sdfsf sfsddffds ss ssf fsdf sdf sfs fsdfs sdfsdf sdf sdf 
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work when you change the span to a div is that the header element is used to represent the introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element

A div on the other hand is not a sectioning element, so ideally it's not correct to use a div inside the header.
Please refer the documentation for further details:
'http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element'

Comment: But OP changes `h2` to `div`, not `span` to `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `.css` provided by jQuery?

```
$('.jtextfill2').css('font-size', '36px');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VaMoose/9n0zreuq/1/)

Comment: That would not fit into the div.